# iPhone: Trouble Playing Video in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, video, ios5, uiimagepickercontroller

In my iPhone app, I am taking video using ImagePickerview and storing it to document directory

For iOS4 (device iPod) I can play video stored in document directory but for iOS 5 (device iPad) the same code is not working for playing video.

so for iOS 5 is there any different way for storing and playing video from document directory

(I also tried with library directory)

```
  -(IBAction)saveVideo:(id)sender
    {  
    imagepicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
      imagepicker.delegate=self;
     if([UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        [imagepicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
        [imagepicker setMediaTypes:[UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]];

         [imagepicker setCameraDevice:UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo];

        [self presentModalViewController:imagepicker animated:YES];

    } 


 }



    - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
  {


     NSMutableString *tempPath = [[[info valueForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL"] absoluteString] mutableCopy];
    NSString *newPath1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myVideo.mov"];
   [tempPath replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"file://localhost/private/" withString:@"/" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [tempPath length])];
   NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
   NSError *error = nil;
  [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject], newPath1];
   NSString *newPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject], newPath1];


   BOOL success = [manager copyItemAtPath:tempPath toPath:newPath error:&error];

     if(error){         
    NSLog(@"New Path: %@", newPath);
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
  }

   if(success)
   {
    NSLog(@"Succeed");     
   }
     [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
   }


    - (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
   {
   [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
   }


    -(IBAction)playVideo:(id)sender
    {
    NSArray *path=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [path objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *myDBnew = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myVideo.mov"];

     NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:myDBnew];
    NSLog(@"URL== %@",url);
    moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                    initWithContentURL:url];

    //        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
    //                                                 selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
    //                                                     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
    //                                                   object:moviePlayer];

    moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
    moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
    [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
    }
```

What could be wrong?

Here is the code.

If I add the video file into my project and use below code it is playing Video The only thing is it is not playing video from document directory

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"myVideo" ofType:@"mov"]];
    moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                    initWithContentURL:url];
```

Even in iTunes via flittering I can see the file:"myVideo.mov", after running the app in device means This codes recording and storing video but not able to read or play.

Comment: My suggestion is to show us the code you use to store and play the video, otherwise we have no idea what you are doing wrong.

Comment: I have posted whole code please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here in my code the problem was  the way i am creating url

```
   NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:myDBnew];
```

which doesn't work for ios5 so i replaced in code by

```
  NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:<#(NSString *)#> isDirectory:<#(BOOL)#>];
```